# Protractor - Eclipse - Run Configurations - Missing Protractor Options

Tags: node.js, angularjs, protractor

Hi people: I need your help.

I try to Run Protractor in Eclipse IDE. I already have installed the plugins:

```
* Angular Eclipse (Outdated)
* Wild Web Developer
* Nodeclipse.github.io
```

I already setted the porject to Tern
Already chosen Protractor, Jasmine, Etc, Etc...

My program versions:

```
npm: 6.12.1
node: v13.1.0
Protractor: 5.4.2
Java:. openjdk version "13.0.1" 2019-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 13.0.1+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing)
```

And, in the Eclipse Run Configurations, **Protractor is Missing**:

Can you help me???

[image]

Answer (score 0):

install Tern Eclipse IDE plugin

Create a Java project and convert it in to Tern project, you will ask to select the modules, leave the one's that
automatically selected and in addition select
Angular JS
Browser
Browser extention
Protractor
Jasmine.

Then in project level write click and create a new file
It is a must to have .spec.js for spec files
Syntax filename.spec.js

Comment: you need node js installed
https://nodejs.org/en/download/ download windows installer install it then npm -v 

Add path to path variable C:\Users\sam\AppData\Roaming\npm


To install protractor ?
npm install -g protractor

To check the version protractor --version